# If you believe that video games that contain violence are makruh are you committing the 60th major sin in islam

Tags: halal-haram, sin, makruh

If you believe that a video game is makruh am I committing the 60th major sin in Islam if you don’t know what it is go on YouTube and watch the video 70 major sins in Islam and go to the 60th major sin “who ever argues in something that is wrong and he knows it Allah will be Angry at him until he stops.”

Answer (score 0):

The lists of «major sins» do not have only differing numbering but in details also differing contents. The major sins do not have the same weight, either.

To evaluate whether something is halal, makruh, haram, a major sin or a capital sin is usually the task of a scholar, and the results are not always the same at least in neighbouring categories.

So if you believe it is makruh and others say it is haram, this is not a sin. It is only the detail between «you should not do» and «you must not do», the message is the same.

The major sin «#60» is if you declare good what is forbidden, willingly putting your own goals over Gods commands although you know better.